# Python: Strange List Indexing Behavior

Tags: python, list

I'm creating a list of lists of lists. When I choose a specific index, it sets several list entries simultaneously. What's going on here?

```
x = []
for i in range(3,6+1,1):
    x.append([['','']] * i)

x[0][0][0] = 1
for col in x:
    print col
```

output:

```
[[1, ''], [1, ''], [1, '']]
[['', ''], ['', ''], ['', ''], ['', '']]
[['', ''], ['', ''], ['', ''], ['', ''], ['', '']]
[['', ''], ['', ''], ['', ''], ['', ''], ['', ''], ['', '']]
```

It's still an open question as to why that doesn't work... Here's a solution, though...

```
x = []
for i in range(3,6+1,1):
    y = ['','']
    tmp = []
    for j in range(i):
        tmp.append(y[:])
    x.append(tmp)

x[0][0][0] = 1
for col in x:
    print col
```

output:

```
[[1, ''], ['', ''], ['', '']]
[['', ''], ['', ''], ['', ''], ['', '']]
[['', ''], ['', ''], ['', ''], ['', ''], ['', '']]
[['', ''], ['', ''], ['', ''], ['', ''], ['', ''], ['', '']]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you multiply the list, objects are re-used, so when you modify one of them, you appear to modify "all" of them. In fact, there is only one inner list, but it appears in multiple places in the outer list!

```
>>> x = []
>>> x.append([['','']] * 3)
>>> x
[[['', ''], ['', ''], ['', '']]]
>>> x[0][0][0] = 1
>>> x
[[[1, ''], [1, ''], [1, '']]]
```

If the inner lists are created separately, so that they are distinct objects, you don't get this problem:

```
>>> x = [[]]
>>> x[0].append(['',''])
>>> x[0].append(['',''])
>>> x[0].append(['',''])
>>> x
[[['', ''], ['', ''], ['', '']]]
>>> x[0][0][0] = 1
>>> x
[[[1, ''], ['', ''], ['', '']]]
```

If you create the list using a comprehension, you also avoid the problem, for example:

```
x = [[['',''] for _ in range(3)]]
```

Comment: Yeah... Isn't this a pretty undesirable characteristic of python?

Comment: If you think of it as duplicating a list of pointers (to inner lists) then I think it makes more sense...